# How to update favicon for pdf vewer?

Tags: html, .net

I am new to Web-Dev so I apologize if this is trivial or poor coding practice.

I changed the favicon for my site, after some errors I found I needed to add ?v=2 for it to display the newest favicon.

```
<link rel="icon" href="~/favicon.ico?v=2"/>
```

On my site users can view a PDF document in a new tab. When the new tab opens the old favicon is still displayed not the new one. I cannot find where to update the favicon for new tabs. I am building this with the .net framework.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When the PDF viewer is up, there's no HTML there that you can control. I believe if you replace the `favicon.ico` in the root of your host, that should apply.

Comment: So I tried this, but it still defaults to the original favicon.ico